# Laravel 5: Get jobs count between min and max salary ranges

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, eloquent

I want to get the jobs count between the min and max salary.
If first case condition satisfies it skips the rest of the case conditions.
Can any one please suggest me to execute all the case condition even if the first condition is satisfies.

**Query:**

```
Job::selectRaw("(
   CASE WHEN (
      0 BETWEEN min_salary AND max_salary 
      OR 200000 BETWEEN min_salary AND max_salary) 
   THEN '0-2 Lacs' 
      WHEN (
         '200000' BETWEEN min_salary AND max_salary OR '400000' 
         BETWEEN min_salary AND max_salary
      ) 
  THEN '2-4 Lacs' ELSE '4+' END) AS salaryrange,
  count(*) as aggregate")
  ->groupBy('salaryrange')
  ->get();
```

**Job Table:**

```
job_title   min_salary   max_salary
Job_1       150000       150000
Job_2       300000       800000
Job_3       150000       300000
Job_4       150000       500000
```

**Current Results:**

```
salaryrange aggregate
0-2 Lacs    2
2-4 Lacs    1
```

**Expected Results:**

```
salaryrange aggregate
0-2 Lacs    2
2-4 Lacs    3
```

Comment: But you do also have 4+ salaries, so why don't you want to include those in the results?

Comment: you should use `if` `else` instead of case for this job.In SQL case is not designed for this type of conditions.

Comment: @Strawberry 4+ having 1 results.